# Вставка изображения из файла

Tags: jogl, java, opengl

Как вставить картинку на холст с помощью OpenGL (Java, JOGL)? Ну или хотя бы не на Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ну или хотя бы не на Java.

Но ведь хотя бы на OpenGL? ) Общая идея такая:

1. Загрузите картинку в виде массива пикселов. Это сильно зависит от того, в каком формате у вас изображение. Но, подходящую библиотеку всегда можно найти (для Java сгодится [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com)).
2. Создайте текстуру в видеопамяти.

   ```
   glGenTextures(...);
   ```
3. Привяжите данные картинки к текстуре.

   ```
   glBindTexture(...);
   glTexImage2D(...);
   ```
4. Нарисуйте четырехугольник, используя подготовленную текстуру.

   ```
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glVertex2d(0,0); glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
   glVertex2d(100,0); glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
   glVertex2d(100,100); glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
   glVertex2d(0,100); glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
   glEnd();
   ```

ЗЫ. Чтобы разобраться, что к чему в OpenGL, рекомендую [цикл статей от NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).